# Distinct values of a column from a very large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a very large table with 1 billion rows and 12 columns, which are `int`, `double`, `varchar`. I need to know the distinct values for each volume.

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct a.id) as num_dist_id
 FROM my_large_table as a

SELECT distinct a.id
 FROM my_large_table as a
```

It is very slow.

Are there better ways to do that ?

**---------------- update --------------------**

the table has columns :

```
 id   id_1   id_2  id_3  id_4  id_5  id_6  id_7  id_8  id_9  id_10  id_11 

SELECT distinct a.id , a.id_1 , a.id_2, a.id_3, a.id_4, a.id_5, a.id_6 ... 
 FROM my_large_table as a
 ORDER BY a.id, a.id_1, a.id_2
```

Can speed up the query ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is there are reason you can't use a unique or primary index on my_large_table.id?

Comment: What indexes are on this table?

Comment: @evanv - what could be a good reason to not use indexes on table of this size ?

Comment: I can think of a lot of good reasons to not use indexes (plural) on a table this size, but few (if any) to not index a column for which the number of distinct ids in this table is an important bit of information that must reported on, and in a way that is not "very slow." I can think of reasons to either use a very high powered machine for this database, or move it to something like Hadoop. But to say that the table just shouldn't have an index... I think that's misguided.

Comment: The table was created by others. it has three Primary keys. one is id,, one is id_1, another id_2. I need to find disinct values for all columns. i am new to index. How create indicies for all columns ? And, i do not want to change the structure of the table. Thanks !

Comment: It can't have three primary keys. Can you post the create table statement?

Comment: @evanv, I am new to SQL. But, the table has three columns marked as PK, so i think it has 3 keys, right ?

Comment: You need to post the create table statement. And no, the second query will not be any faster than the first. In fact it will be much (much, much, much, much, much) slower. But ultimately the question is, what is your table schema (share the create table statement)? And what do you actually need here? The first query does not tell you unique ids across all columns, It gives you unique ids for one column. Maybe that's all you need. But it's not clear from what you've shared what you're actually trying to do. You've essentially said two very different things

Comment: as an aside, it's generally a pretty idea to use ORDER BY on a table with a billion records..... if it's ordered by an indexed column, maybe.... but I would avoid the order by if it all possible.

Comment: You cannot do anything to make this query faster without adding appropriate indexing. SQL Server is capable of generating the perfect execution plan for such simple queries. Rewrites do not help.

Comment: @evanv, I do not have the table create statement. It was created by others. I need to find distinct column values for each column. Fo example, for id (= 1) how many distinct values of id_1, for id_1 (= 11) how many distinct values of id_2, and so on. I also need to know the distinct values for each column without grouping. For example, how many distinct id_1 values in the table ? thanks !

Comment: without knowing the details about the indices it is impossible to recommend anything. but it seems very unlikely to me that each of these ids is in fact a unique key by itself... and if not, there is no fast way to perform this.

Answer (score 3):

Create an indexed view for each column that you want to query this way. Realize, that `DISTINCT` is equivalent to a `GROUP BY` on all columns. The view would look like this:

```
SELECT MyCol, COUNT_BIG(*) Count FROM T GROUP BY MyCol
```

Now create an index on it. In Enterprise edition this index will automatically speed up your original query. In Standard Edition you need to query this view directly with `NOEXPAND`.

The query will then execute as a trivial index scan. It can read the exact results you want off of an index. Doesn't get any faster.

Comment: The table was created by others. it has three Primary keys. one is id,, one is id_1, another id_2. I need to find disinct values for all columns. i am new to index. How create indicies for all columns ? And, i do not want to change the structure of the table. Thanks !

Comment: @user3448011, if it's already has a PK then try doing a group by on that PK column. That's will definitely speed up your query processing.

Comment: Double check the primary key....it cannot have three of the,. That does not make sense.

Comment: Sounds like he's just mistaking three primary keys with one primary key consisting of three columns.

Comment: Maybe. But without the create table, who knows? And if the pk is based on three columns, does he need unique in terms of only one of those columns? Maybe. It's very possible... but it still seems like there's some confusion regarding the schema and what exact thing needs to be accomplished here.

Comment: @evanv, I am new to SQL. But, the table has three columns marked as PK, so i think it has 3 keys, right ?

Comment: It's true that a create table script would eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: Create an index **on this view** not on the base table. You don't need to modify the table at all.

Comment: @usr, would you please show me some SQL code about how to create index only on this view ? I am new to SQL. Thanks !

Comment: Certainly not, but I can only recommend that you use your favorite search engine to search for "sql server create index on view".